# Extract graph from git log

Tags: git

The output of `git log --graph` is a representation of a directed acyclic graph. I want an adjacency list representation of this graph (or the ability to construct such a representation). However, I cannot figure out how to show information about parents in the graph rather than parent commits. This seems like it would be a common problem for people attempting to analyze git repositories, so it must be a solved problem. Can someone point me in the right direction? (Perhaps I'm missing something entirely obvious).

Comment: Rather than trying to interpret the drawn graph, use `git rev-list --parents`, which lists commit hash IDs with their parent hash IDs (i.e., the outgoing arcs—the Git graph is reversed from the typical representation, with descendants pointing to their parents, rather than parent nodes pointing to children).

Comment: easiest would be to point you to ready solution, and I have [some](https://github.com/max630/git-rehi/blob/master/app/Rehi.hs). I cannot put a line link from mobile, but search for functions `git_fetch_cli_commits` and `git_parse_commit_line` - it's very straightforward.